# How can i implement a running total in django Template?

Tags: django

I have a view that returns my sales summary grouped by sales_date e.g.

```
[{'sale_date':datetime.datetime(2010,10,5,0,0), 'salesum':2, 'item':1},
 {'sale_date':datetime.datetime(2010,10,5,0,0), 'salesum':10,'item':3},
 {'sale_date':datetime.datetime(2010,10,6,0,0), 'salesum':1, 'item':1}]
```

I have done the grouping inside the template, and combined it with html **ul** and **li** tags to give me a nice grouping effect based on the sale_date

My template grouping is based on this code:

```
{% regroup salecursor by sale_date|date:"j/m/Y" as salelist %}
```

and

```
{{ saleitem.grouper }
```

The result is:

**05/10/2010**

- item1 Name - 2
- item2 Name - 10

**06/10/2010**

- Item1 Name - 1

How do u get a running total for each group i.e. group one should have a total of 12 and the second group a total of 1 and have something of this effect;

**05/10/2010**

- item1 Name - 2
- item2 Name - 10

  **Total 12**

**06/10/2010**

- Item1 Name - 1

  **Total 1**

Thanks
Gath

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What? Don't you know of the `running_total` filter?

Just kidding there. There isn't one such but it is pretty easy to write one. This is a bit inefficient as it traverses the grouped list again to `sum` the `salesum` values.

```
# app_filters.py
@register.filter
def running_total(sales_list):
    return sum(d.get('salesum') for d in sales_list)
```

And you can use it thus in your template:

```
{% regroup salecursor by sale_date|date:"j/m/Y" as salelist %}

<ul>
{% for sales in salelist %}
    <li>{{ sales.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in sales.list %}
        <li>{{ item.item }} - {{ item.salesum }}</li>
        {% endfor %}

        <li>Total: <b>{{ sales.list|running_total }}</b></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. In my case, I needed to address the objects this way: `sum(d.salesum for d in salelist)` or else I got a `"Sale" has no attribute "get"` error.

Comment: Really a nice solution. Thanks a lot