# Django in template - total of list after regrouping

Tags: django, templates

I am using Django in template to regroup a multidimensional list based on the category field. Per category I also need the sum of an integer field from the same list. I've read through a number of questions about this and it seems that I would have to do this in the view, before the template renders. However this would mean that I have to separately define the total for each category, whereas I was hoping that the regroup would save me this trouble. Is there any alternative or another better way of doing this?

```
{% regroup shops|dictsort:"category" by category as category_list %}
{% for clist in category_list %}
# here should come the total per category
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create function inside your model then call it in your template.

```
Category(models.Model)
    ........

    def total(self):
        qs = Category.objects.filter(id=self).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
        sum = qs['amount__sum']
        if not sum:
            sum = 0.00
        return sum

{% regroup shops|dictsort:"category" by category as category_list %}
{% for clist in category_list %}
    {{clist}} - {{clist.total}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Kind of lost focus on this one. Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would answer your question, [How can i implement a running total in django Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921252/how-can-i-implement-a-running-total-in-django-template). The title is a bit confusing but I think you can get something there.